# jQuery: Toggleable path-like navigation with decorations

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$("#one_link").click(function() {
  $("#categories").toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); //Active class
  $(this).prepend("▶&nbsp;"); //Should toggle and not insert over and over again
  $("#text_three").hide();
  $("#cats_text").hide();
  $("#text_two").hide();
});

$("#cats_link").click(function() {
  $("#cats_text").toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); //Active class
  $(this).prepend("▶&nbsp;"); //Should toggle and not insert over and over again
  $("#text_two").hide();
  $("#text_three").hide();
});

$("#two_link").click(function() {
  $("#text_two").toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); //Active class
  $(this).prepend("▶&nbsp;"); //Should toggle and not insert over and over again
  $("#categories").hide();
  $("#cats_text").hide();
  $("#text_three").hide();
});

$("#three_link").click(function() {
  $("#text_three").toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); //Active class
  $(this).prepend("▶&nbsp;"); //Should toggle and not insert over and over again
  $("#categories").hide();
  $("#cats_text").hide();
  $("#text_two").hide();
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: Arial;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.column_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column {
  display: none;
}

.column:first-child {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="column_content">
      <ul>
        <li id="one_link">One</li>
        <li id="two_link">Two</li>
        <li id="three_link">Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="categories" class="column">
    <div class="column_content">
      <ul>
        <li id="cats_link">Cats</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column" id="cats_text">
    <div class="column_content">
      <p>The cat (Felis catus) is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal. It is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column" id="text_two">
    <div class="column_content">
      <p>2 (two) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 1 and preceding 3. It is the smallest and only even prime number. Because it forms the basis of a duality, it has religious and spiritual significance in many cultures.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column" id="text_three">
    <div class="column_content">
      <p>3 (three) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 2 and preceding 4, and is the smallest odd prime number. It has religious or cultural significance in many societies.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you click only »One« and then »Cats«, it looks exactly how it should be. 
But if you click then for example »Two« or »Three«, then »One« has still a text-decoration. This shouldn't happen, it should also toggle.
Furthermore, the »▶« should be a part of this marking. It should be inserted at most once before each link.

Ah and I will need more categories, so it would be great if it were easily expandable.

Can someone help me?

Would be very happy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say that this is perfect, but I made some improvements.

For starters I cut down on the amount of repetitive Javascript by leveraging HTML attributes like `class` and some `data-*`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Also note that I moved your `▶` into a pseudo element on the `active` class.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

```js
$('.tab-opening-button').click(function(){ 
  const openId = $(this).attr('data-open');
  const linkParent = $(this).attr('data-parent-link');
  if(!linkParent){
      $('#categories').hide();
  }
  $('.text-panel').hide();
  $(openId).show();
  
  $('.tab-opening-button').not(linkParent).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  border-right: 3px solid;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.text-panel {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.column_content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column {
  display: none;
}

.column:first-child {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline yellow;
}

.active:before {
  content: "▶ "
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

    <div class="column">
        <div class="column_content">
            <ul>
                <li data-open="#categories" class="tab-opening-button" id="one_link">One</li>
                <li data-open="#text_two" class="tab-opening-button" id="two_link">Two</li>
                <li data-open="#text_three" class="tab-opening-button" id="three_link">Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="categories" class="column">
        <div class="column_content">
            <ul>
                <li data-open="#cats_text" data-parent-link="#one_link"  class="tab-opening-button" id="cats_link">Cats</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column text-panel" id="cats_text">
        <div class="column_content">
            <p>The cat (Felis catus) is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal. It is the only domesticated
                species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the
                wild members of the family.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column text-panel" id="text_two">
        <div class="column_content">
            <p>2 (two) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 1 and preceding 3. It is the
                smallest and only even prime number. Because it forms the basis of a duality, it has religious and
                spiritual significance in many cultures.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column text-panel" id="text_three">
        <div class="column_content">
            <p>3 (three) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 2 and preceding 4, and is
                the smallest odd prime number. It has religious or cultural significance in many societies.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is a pity that the toggle function is away now. And text goes over the columns. Hm ... I'll think about it and maybe edit the question, but thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by the text goes over the columns?

Comment: This is what I mean: https://pasteboard.co/J3ptvCnt.png – The content of the text links should define the widths of the columns.

Comment: Updated. The fix involved setting "flex-shrink" appropriately and also the use of the box-sizing property.

Comment: Did that fix what you are talking about on your end? (with the browser you are using?)